# Retrieve linux password for current user

Tags: php, linux, security, passwords

I am trying implement a php script for multiple clients that requires the use of their cpanel/linux username and password. To avoid having to set it up individually of each customer I would like to be able to atomically set the 3 vars that are required,  username and password.  Username have done as follows

$user = exec('whoami');

Is there any way to retrieve that password also?

Thank

Comment: oh that would be safe :(

Comment: passwords stored in /etc/passwd (oldschool) and /etc/shadow (newschool) are unretrievable. they're hashed 1-way.

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcshadow-file/

Comment: well yes but I am not counting out a solution that maybe retrieves via a shell script in non-web dir?

Comment: the password is hashed, how ever you retrieve it, it wound be of any use.

Answer (score 6):

That would be a major security flaw! You can never retrieve a users password, you can only change it if you have root permissions. Passwords in linux are encrypted in a one-way fashion. Ie you can go from plain text to hash, but you can never go back from has to plain text.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to retrive an linux users password in plain text.

Cpanel has an API. Use that to login your users instead.

Comment: And if it were, it would be very bad :)